# Problem with an iCalendar Feed

Tags: php, icalendar

I'm outputting my iCalendar feed via PHP and it seems to work fine validation wise and when importing into iCal on the mac and windows calendar on vista however Google calendar throws it out completely...

www.wheresthegeeks.co.uk/calendar/ical

can anyone have a gander and give me some suggestion to see whats wrong?

thanks a lot

Dom

Answer (score 0):

I put it into a [calendar validation script](http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/?url=www.wheresthegeeks.co.uk%2Fcalendar%2Fical) and that says no problem. It initially failed when I put the same URL into Gcal, but then when I also added the leading 'http://', it was fine. It looks like Google Calendar requires the full schema-specified URL.

Comment: I've tried it with http://www and without the www but all I get is We "could not parse the calendar at the URL requested" thanks though

Comment: Having the same problem here as well, but I suspect httpS is the culprit -- The same static .ics file works fine in Google Calendar when served from a non-secure http-address, but fails when served from a secure https-address (with valid certificate and all).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and the reason was URL length limits. Anything over 256 characters and Google Calendar will not work unless you use a URL shortener like goo.gl.